# Regarding my ARM template using as a Dynamic one with the help of KeyVault and Replace Tokens

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have ARM templates in my azure git repos. I am deploying through ARM template task. Currently all the variables in the arm templates are hardcoded. As I need to deploy ARM template in multiple environments, I am using replace token task and some secret values needs to fetch from azure keyvault. But it is bot working as expected.

[image: Screenshot of the pipeline configuration]

I have ARM templates in my azure git repos. I am deploying through ARM template task. Currently all the variables in the arm templates are hardcoded. As I need to deploy ARM template in multiple environments, I am using replace token task and some secret values needs to fetch from azure keyvault. But it is bot working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To pass ARM template variables dynamically, first, you hmust create a pattern for all the variables you want to pass dynamically as shown below.
[image]

Next, define variables for this template in pipeline variables and select the required scope.
[image]
Next, add replace token task in the pipeline. It must be placed before the ARM template.
[image]
In the above screenshot, the token pattern must match the pattern defined in the parameters.json file.

To fetch secrets from the key vault, kindly refer to this link [Use Azure key vault secrets in Azure Pipelines | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).